# How to set backView color in UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I want to change the back page color of `UIPageViewController`, from white to some image. I had tried to achieve it from previous stackoverflow suggestions But I am not able to get how to do it.  Can anyone suggest to me what exactly I need to do?

```
-(void) createPages{ 
  self.pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:6];
  CountViewController *controller; 
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"countView"]; 
   controller.pageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
   [controller.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
   [self.pages addObject:controller]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: put some code. how you created pageview

Comment: -(void) createPages{
    
    self.pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:6];
    
    CountViewController *controller;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"countView"];
        controller.pageNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
        
        [controller.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.pages addObject:controller];
        
    }

}

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the window background color. You should set the window background color:

```
appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: I dont want black color always.. i want to change it according to front view bgImage & i tried with appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; but no changes..